# TypeError trying to concatenate lists in Dask

Tags: python, dask

How can I concatenate a series of lists in Dask?

The following code using `da.concatenate` results in this error:

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
def concat_lists(s):

    # Binarize connectors
    tmp = da.concatenate(s.values)

    return tmp

concat_lists(dd.from_pandas(pd.Series([["1","2"], ["1"], ["3", "2"], ["1"]]), npartitions=1)).compute()
```

The desired result would be a single dask array or Series like ["1","2","1","3","2","1"]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `da.concatenate` function consumes a list of dask arrays and produces a single dask array of all of them concatenated together.

You seem to be giving it a single dask array rather than a list, which is what is causing the error.  I suspect that you may be looking for a different function than `da.concatenate`

Comment: I'm providing a pandas Series of lists. Before I tried providing a list of lists and an array of lists. I tried several things. Do I need to convert the inner lists (e.g. ["1","2"]) to dask arrays?

I'll update my question with the result I'm looking for

Comment: da.concatenate doesn't do that.  I recommend reading the docstring.  I encourage you to figure out how you would solve your problem with pandas and then use the map_partitions method.

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back